# Conservation of energy doubt

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

[image]

I was reading feynman lectures volume 1 in the 4th chapter. In the part I just highlighted how can we obtain free power from lowering machine b? Any help is appreciated

Comment: You cannot. Read the rest of the paragraph and the next one. Think about what Y and X represent and how they relate to each other.

Comment: @electronpusher If you read the part immediately before the highlighted part, you can see that Feynman is doing a proof by contradiction, so it is valid to ask you one would obtain free power in this context.

Answer (score 1):

If machine A and B both could exist, we could use them to create extra energy in the Universe. We could use this as an energy source to for example run another machine M. Here is how it could work: the starting configuration is with one weight at height $1$ ft., and the stack of 3 weights on top of eachother on the ground. Move the weights onto macine B (note that moving weights horizontally, i.e. not against gravity, is not considered to require energy in this thougth experiment). Now use machine B to lift the stack of weights to height $y$. Then move the stack of weights onto e.g. a piston that drives M. Let the weight of the stack push the piston down the distance $y -x$. Note that positive work is being done on the piston, so energy is supplied to M. When the stack is at height $x$, move it onto macine A, and move the weight that is on the ground onto the other end of A. Use A to lower the stack to the ground lifting the single weight to height 1 ft. (Note that A is reversible, so running it in "reverse", i.e. lifting the single weight and lowering the stack dose not require energy). Now move the weights onto machine B and repeat.